# Exporting issues to excel using openpyxl(django) (cant seems to work with fetchall())

Tags: mysql, django, openpyxl

> ```
> def export_as_xls(self, request, queryset):
>     opts = self.model._meta
>     file_name = unidecode(opts.verbose_name)
>     sql_query = '''SELECT  
>                     COUNT(id) AS No_Of_Report, 
>                     vendor, 
>                     country_code, 
>                     SUM(new_code)*100/SUM(sent) AS 'failure_rate', 
>                     SUM(case when new_code =0 then 1 ELSE 0 end)*100/sum(sent) AS 'success_rate' 
>                     FROM sms_statistics 
>                     WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date) >= curdate() - interval 30 day
>                     GROUP BY vendor, country_code 
>                     ORDER BY vendor DESC;'''
> ```

This is mysql query i used to call for the data in mysql schema

> ```
>     field_names = ('No of report', 'Vendor', 'Country Code', 'Failure Rate', 'Success Rate')
>     wb = Workbook()
>     ws = wb.active
>     ws.append(ExportExcelAction.generate_header(self, self.model, field_names))
>     with connection.cursor() as cursor:
>         cursor.execute(sql_query)
>         objects = list(cursor.fetchall())
>         for row in cursor.fetchall():
>             objects = list(row)
>             ws.append(objects)
>             print(ws.append(row))
>     ws = style_output_file(ws)
> ```
>
> I think the issue is right here for not being able to export to excel. Im not be using the right method to export the file from action.py

response =
HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={file_name}.xlsx'
wb.save(response)
return response
export_as_xls.short_description = "Reports of Past 30 days"
export_as_xls.acts_on_all = True

> Blockquote

I believe this part is fine as i tried exporting an empty file and its working as expexted

Answer (score 0):

```
def export_thirty_days(self, request, queryset):
    opts = self.model._meta
    file_name = "Sms Statistic Report"
    sql_query = '''SELECT  
                    COUNT(id) AS No_Of_Report, 
                    vendor, 
                    country_code, 
                    SUM(new_code)*100/SUM(sent) AS 'failure_rate', 
                    SUM(case when new_code =0 then 1 ELSE 0 end)*100/sum(sent) AS 'success_rate' 
                    FROM sms_statistics 
                    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date) >= curdate() - interval 30 day
                    GROUP BY vendor, country_code 
                    ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC;'''
    field_names = ('No of report', 'Vendor', 'Country Code', 'Failure Rate', 'Success Rate')
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(ExportExcelAction.generate_header(self, self.model, field_names))
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            l = list(row)
            ws.append(l)
    ws = style_output_file(ws)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={file_name}.xlsx'
    wb.save(response)
    return response
export_thirty_days.short_description = "Reports of Past 30 days"
export_thirty_days.acts_on_all = True
```

> This is the solutions i've found to make it work